# Application of Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability

The majority function is defined as $\text{Maj}_{n}:\{-1,1\}^{n} \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ with  $$\text{Maj}_{n}(x)=\text{sgn}\left(x_{1}+\dots+x_{n}\right)$$ I would like to prove that for any $ \varepsilon  > 0 $, there exists a constant $ C=C(\varepsilon)>0 $ such that $$\mathbb{Pr}\left(\text{Maj}_{n}(x)=1\mid x_{1}=\ldots=x_{\left[C\sqrt{n}\right]}=+1\right) \geq 1-\varepsilon $$ where $ [x] $ denotes the integral part of real $ x $.

In terms of social choice, the problem says that there is a constant $ C $ such that the $ +1 $ candidate can bribe no more than $ C\sqrt{n} $ such that the probability that he wins the majority election is bigger than $ 1-\varepsilon $.

I know that I should somehow use the Central Limit Theorem, but I don't know how.

Thank you in advance for any hints and suggestions!

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\operatorname{Maj}_n(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x_1+\ldots+x_n)$?

Comment: Hint: the probability of complementary event is $\mathbb{P} (x_{[C\sqrt{n}]+1}+ x_{[C\sqrt{n}]+2} + \dots+ x_{n} <-C\sqrt{n})$. Use Chebyshev's inequality (CLT is too powerful for this simple fact) to show that the latter probability goes to $0$ as $C\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to solve it using your remark.